# How can I plot date on x-axis and price list on y-axis and attribute by using ggplot?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I am trying to use `ggplot` to draw the data contained in the following date frame:

```
df <- data.frame( dress_id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  29/8/2013 = c(2000,150,6,1000,900),
                  31/8/2013 = c(2000,200,7,1100,1000),
                  2/9/2013 = c(2400,600,7,1350,1300),
                  4/9/2013 = c(2600,600,7,1500,1400),
                  style = c("Sexy", "Casual","vintage","Brief","cute"))
```

I want to have x-axis to be my date (29/8/2013...2/9/2013) and my y-axis to be the sales price of dates and finally my style.

Is this possible using ggplot?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, what is the expected output? First, convert your data wide-to-long, then convert "dates" into class of date, then plot.

Comment: I want to see make a linear regression. the file is big. I just write down the first line of file. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I am new in R so what do you mean by convert the data wide-to-long?

Comment: No problems, try to search "r convert the data wide-to-long".

Comment: I am reading about wide to long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the details to zx8754's answer.
First, note that I put an `X` infront of the date columns: this is because column-names in R should not start with a number.

```
df <- data.frame( dress_id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                  "X29/8/2013" = c(2000,150,6,1000,900),
                  "X31/8/2013" = c(2000,200,7,1100,1000),
                  "X2/9/2013" = c(2400,600,7,1350,1300),
                  "X4/9/2013" = c(2600,600,7,1500,1400),
                  style = c("Sexy", "Casual","vintage","Brief","cute"))
```

Next, I load the `tidyverse` package, which contains functions to work with data.frames and also includes `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Finally, I transform your data from wide to long: this is done with the `gather` functions. As a result, there is now a date column in your data.frame which contains all the present dates and a value column which contains the sales prices.

```
df %>%
  gather(date, value, -dress_id, -style) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = c("X%d.%m.%Y"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value, colour = style)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe use `pivot_longer` instead of `gather`.

Comment: I do have a one problem why is my date is change from 2013 to from 2013 to 2017??? furthermore, what is the function of mutate here?

Comment: hi, `mutate` is used to transform the initial date column which is in character format to date format. This is necessary if you want to plot your data.